How do I add able to a word ending in a consonant?
How do I add able to a word ending in a consonant? For example, fret with able added will become fretable or frettable as an expression of the possibility of playing something on guitar.

If candidates are not listed in quality online dictionaries (and Wiktionary should be included amongst these. It has the largest number of headwords) then one must ask if they are true words. Affixation isn't absolutely productive. A D-I-Y protologism may or may not be acceptable to various audiences, but protologisms are off-topic on ELU. / Note that regrettable and forgettable etc are formed by  doubling the t. The perhaps unlikely bettable, ditto [Wiktionary]. 'Whettable' isn't listed in Wiktionary. 'Wettable' of course is.

If you have a Linux or Mac, use grep '[^aeiou]able$' /usr/share/dict/words to find all the words ending in able with a consonant before it.

Some common examples: "workable", "walkable", "waggable", "returnable". Whether you double the consonant varies. I think you generally need to double it if a short vowel in the last syllable would change to long without it.

See if your dictionary has freted or fretted;  also fretting or freting.  If some of these exist, copy them for fretable or frettable.

English has general spelling rules for adding suffixes and morphemes like -ing, although they vary a bit between US and UK. You can also think about pronunciation and syllabification.
